# Power Management for days of the week

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I was wondering if Windows 7 had a way to configure different power management options for certain days of the week?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but you could create different profiles (`Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > Create Power plan`) and use the task scheduler (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> taskschd.msc) to launch the **powercfg** command:

```
powerfcfg -S "name of your power plan"
```

(`powercfg -L` in a command prompt to list all profiles)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be the power management utility Granola - it allows scheduling CPU power usage by the hour and day, which may be useful.

Comment: Can you add a link and a short explanation of how that works, maybe?